# How did this character appear at the end of The Flash season 2 finale?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In *The Flash* season 2 finale, "The Race of His Life", after

> Zoom kidnaps Joe

we are shown a scene on Earth-2, where we can see that

> Zoom is still holding the masked man prisoner in his cell.

Flash later contacts Zoom and tells him

> that he'll agree to the race on the condition that he brings Joe back to Earth-1 with him.

Later, Zoom agrees to this condition and appears

> with Joe, but not with the masked man, who is presumably still locked up in his cell.

Yet after the climax of the episode,

> Harry and Cisco are suddenly shown removing the masked man's mask, revealing him to be the "real" Jay Garrick of Earth-3, and also Barry's father's doppleganger.

When did this happen?  At what point did

> Earth-3 Jay crossover from Earth-2 to Earth-1?  Did Zoom bring him to Earth-1 with him at the same time he brought Joe (and if so, why would he do that, when it wasn't a condition Barry imposed)?  Did the heroes go to Earth-2 to go get Earth-3 Jay then come back to Earth-1 (and if so, then why did Harry and Cisco not take his mask off then, rather than waiting until they got back)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not shown but I think it's pretty obvious. Once Zoom was defeated there's no reason the team can't cross over between universes at will. Cisco just opened a portal for them and a few of them went over to Zoom's hideout to get the final prisoner.

As far as why they waited until returning to Earth-1 to unmask him, mostly likely they just didn't bring the right tools with them. They probably also wanted to examine him medically and make sure he wasn't ill or malnourished.

Comment: I seem to recall that earlier in the season, Barry promise the masked man that he would come back for him. With Zoom gone, he could finally do that.